# C++ - Using istream_iterator with wstringstream

Tags: c++, unicode, std

I am trying to add Unicode support to a program that I wrote. My ASCII code compiled and had the following lines:

```
std::stringstream stream("abc");
std::istream_iterator<std::string> it(stream);
```

I converted this to:

```
std::wstringstream stream(L"abc");
std::istream_iterator<std::wstring> it(stream);
```

I get the following error in the istream_iterator constructor:

```
error C2664: 'void std::vector<_Ty>::push_back(std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &&)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>' to 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &&'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=std::wstring,
1>              _Elem=wchar_t,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<wchar_t>,
1>              _Alloc=std::allocator<wchar_t>
1>          ]
1>          and
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Alloc=std::allocator<char>
1>          ]
1>          and
1>          [
1>              _Elem=wchar_t,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<wchar_t>,
1>              _Alloc=std::allocator<wchar_t>
1>          ]
1>          Reason: cannot convert from 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>' to 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Alloc=std::allocator<char>
1>          ]
1>          and
1>          [
1>              _Elem=wchar_t,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<wchar_t>,
1>              _Alloc=std::allocator<wchar_t>
1>          ]
1>          No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
```

What is the correct way to convert the code above to Unicode?

Thanks.

**P.S.**

I am running Visual Studio 2012

Comment: No APIs (except Windows, really) use wide characters. If you want to have Unicode support, UTF-8 is the generally accepted option.

Comment: Yes I want my code to support UTF-8. My understanding was that std::wstring was the STL version of UTF-8 string.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try:

```
std::wstringstream stream(L"abc");
std::istream_iterator<std::wstring, wchar_t> it(stream);
```

...and see if it doesn't work better.

Regarding comments: No, this is *not* for UTF-8. It's to (more or less) directly read from a file containing UTF-16 into a string containing UTF-16. Depending on the compiler and what size it uses for `wchar_t`, that could be UTF-32 instead, but (probably) won't ever be UTF-8.

To read UTF-8 from the file and convert to something like UTF-32 for internal use, you might want to look at [Boost.locale](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/locale/doc/html/charset_handling.html), which includes a utf-to-utf codecvt facet.

Comment: Like a charm. Does this work only for UTF-16 or also UTF-8? What is the way to do this for UTF-8?

Comment: @BenjyKessler, There are libraries out there, like ICU, but the premise is to use a `std::string` where the characters are the encoding of a UTF-8 string. @Jerry, C++11 also includes such facilities, although I haven't had much luck with implementation support. Oops, I guess that's discussed on the page.